# Use an indirect proof to show that if $x^3+x-1 \gt 10$ then $x > 1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Use an indirect proof to show that if $x^3+x-1 \gt 10$ then $x > 1$.

Let if possible $x\le 1,$ then how to proceed?

EDITED:

Whole question boils down to how to show that if $x\lt 1$ then $x^3\lt 1$?(without using functions, derivatives )

Comment: Of course, the argument should work for *all* $x\leq 1$ @George, so "subbing in" doesn't quite work.

Comment: If $x \le 1$ then clearly $x^3 \le 1$ and so $ x^3 + x -1$ would be less or equal to $1$.

Comment: @FrancescoChini, then we need to show that $x\le 1 \Rightarrow x^3\le 1$

Comment: True. but $x \to x^3$ is a non decreasing function and $1^3 = 1$.

Comment: @Francesco Chini True, but how to convince someone who do not know about functions.

Comment: You can see that $(x^3)' = 3x^2 \ge 0$. :)

Comment: Sir, if someone even doesn't know about functions then how can we expect that they know about differentiation.

Comment: If this still doesn't convince you, you can try to prove as an exercise that if a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has non-negative derivative, then it must be non-decreasing. :)

Comment: Ok, so we can't use any notion about calculus?

Comment: @FrancescoChini   Exactly ,that is what I wanted.

Comment: Ok I write you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to show that if $x \le 1$, then $x^3 \le 1$ and then we are done. We can't use any notion about calculus, as required in the comments.
If $x$ is negative, then we would get immediately  $x^3 <0 \le 1$. So let's assume $x \ge0$
We know that
$$
x \le 1.
$$ 
Let's multiply each side by $x$.
$$
x^2 \le x \le 1.
$$
Again let's multiply every term by $x$.
$$
x^3 \le x^2 \le x \le 1.
$$

Answer (score 4):

If $x\le 1$ then either $x\le 0$ or $0 < x \le 1$. 
If $x\le 0$ then obviously $x^3\le 0 \le 1$. If $0 < x \le 1$ then multiply the inequality three times with itself (you can do that since both $x$ and $1$ are positive numbers) and you get that $x^3\le 1$.

Thus in any case: 
$x\le 1$ implies $x^3\le 1$. Summation by parts gives $$x^3+x-1\le 1$$
Thus $$x^3+x-1 \gt 10 \gt 1 \Rightarrow x\gt 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Note $f'(x) = 3x^2 + 1 > 0$ hence the function is strictly increasing. We have $f(1) = 1$. Suppose for some $x<1$ , $f(x) > 10$. This contradicts the function being strictly increasing.

Edit: OP asks for a solution without calculus. We have $1^3 + 1 - 1 = 1 < 10$. Suppose $x \in (0,1)$. Then $x^3\in (0,1)$ clearly. This implies $0<x^3 + x < 2$, or $0<x^3 + x - 1 <1<10$.

For $x<0$, $x^3<0$ and $x<0$ so $x^3 + x - 1$ is at most $-1<10$.

$x \leq 1 \Longrightarrow x^3 + x - 1 < 10$. The assertion follows by contraposition.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x < 1$, then $x - 1 < 0 \implies 0 > (x -1)\left[(x + \frac{1}{2})^{2} + \frac{3}{4}\right] = x^{3} - 1$.

Comment: I want an indirect proof.

Comment: I have offered that now in the edited version.